# In Kotlin, how do I add extension methods to another class, but only visible in a certain context?

Tags: dsl, builder, kotlin

In Kotlin, I want to add extension methods to a class, for example to class `Entity`.  But I only want to see these extensions when `Entity` is within a transaction, otherwise hidden.  For example, if I define these classes and extensions:

```kotlin
interface Entity {}

fun Entity.save() {}
fun Entity.delete() {}

class Transaction {
    fun start() {}
    fun commit() {}
    fun rollback() {}
}
```

I now can accidentally call `save()` and `delete()` at any time, but I only want them available after the `start()` of a transaction and no longer after `commit()` or `rollback()`?  Currently I can do this, which is wrong:

```kotlin
someEntity.save()       // DO NOT WANT TO ALLOW HERE
val tx = Transaction()
tx.start()
someEntity.save()       // YES, ALLOW
tx.commit()
someEntity.delete()     // DO NOT WANT TO ALLOW HERE
```

How do I make them appear and disappear in the correct context?

**Note:** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that the idiomatic answers to commonly asked Kotlin topics are present in SO.  Also to clarify some really old answers written for alphas of Kotlin that are not accurate for current-day Kotlin.  Other answers are also welcome, there are many styles of how to answer this!*

Comment: good question! But why 2 answers?

Comment: I wrote one, then I wrote another.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### The Basics:

In Kotlin, we tend to use lambdas passed into other classes to give them "scope" or to have behaviour that happens before and after the lambda is executed, including error handling.  Therefore you first need to change the code for `Transaction` to provide scope.   Here is a modified `Transaction` class:

```
class Transaction(withinTx: Transaction.() -> Unit) {
    init {
        start()
        try {
            // now call the user code, scoped to this transaction class
            this.withinTx()
            commit()
        }
        catch (ex: Throwable) {
            rollback()
            throw ex
        }

    }
    private fun Transaction.start() { ... }

    fun Entity.save(tx: Transaction) { ... }
    fun Entity.delete(tx: Transaction) { ... }

    fun Transaction.save(entity: Entity) { entity.save(this) }
    fun Transaction.delete(entity: Entity) { entity.delete(this) }

    fun Transaction.commit() { ... }
    fun Transaction.rollback() { ... }
}
```

Here we have a transaction that when created, requires a lambda that does the processing within the transaction, if no exception is thrown it auto commits the transaction.  (The constructor of the `Transaction` class is acting like a [Higher-Order Function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions))

We have also moved the extension functions for `Entity` to be within `Transaction` so that these extension functions will not be seen nor callable without being in the context of this class.  This includes the methods of `commit()` and `rollback()` which can only be called now from within the class itself because they are now extension functions scoped within the class.

Since the lambda being received is an extension function to `Transaction` it operates in the context of that class, and therefore sees the extensions. (see: [Function Literals with Receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver))

This old code is now invalid, with the compiler giving us an error:

```
fun changePerson(person: Person) {
    person.name = "Fred" 
    person.save() // ERROR: unresolved reference: save()
}
```

And now you would write the code instead to exist within a `Transaction` block:

```
fun actsInMovie(actor: Person, film: Movie) {
    Transaction {   // optional parenthesis omitted
        if (actor.winsAwards()) {
            film.addActor(actor)
            save(film)
        } else {
            rollback()
        }
    }
}
```

The lambda being passed in is inferred to be an extension function on `Transaction` since it has no formal declaration.

To chain a bunch of these "actions" together within a transaction, just create a series of extension functions that can be used within a transaction, for example:

```
fun Transaction.actsInMovie(actor: Person, film: Movie) {
    film.addActor(actor)
    save(film)
}
```

Create more like this, and then use them in the lambda passed to the Transaction...

```
Transaction { 
   actsInMovie(harrison, starWars)
   actsInMovie(carrie, starWars)
   directsMovie(abrams, starWars)
   rateMovie(starWars, 5)
}
```

Now back to the original question, we have the transaction methods and the entity methods only appearing at the correct moments in time.  And as a side effect of using lambdas or anonymous functions is that we end up exploring new ideas about how our code is composed.

Answer (score 12):

See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34797367/3679676) for the main topic and the basics, *here be deeper waters...*

### Related advanced topics:

We do not solve everything you might run into here.  It is easy to make some extension function appear in the context of another class.  But it isn't so easy to make this work for two things at the same time.  For example, if I wanted the `Movie` method `addActor()` to only appear while inside a `Transaction` block, it is more difficult.  The `addActor()` method cannot have two receivers at the same time.  So we either have a method that receives two parameters `Transaction.addActorToMovie(actor, movie)` or we need another plan.

One way to do this is to use intermediary objects by which we can extend the system.  Now, the following example may or may not be sensible, but it shows how to go this extra level of exposing functions only as desired.  Here is the code, where we change `Transaction` to implement an interface `Transactable` so that we can now [delegate to the interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) whenever we want.

When we add new functionality we can create new implementations of `Transactable` that expose these functions and also holds temporary state.  Then a simple helper function can make it easy to access these hidden new classes.  All additions can be done without modifying the core original classes.

**Core classes:**

```
interface Entity {}

interface Transactable {
    fun Entity.save(tx: Transactable)
    fun Entity.delete(tx: Transactable)

    fun Transactable.commit()
    fun Transactable.rollback()

    fun Transactable.save(entity: Entity) { entity.save(this) }
    fun Transactable.delete(entity: Entity) { entity.save(this) }
}


class Transaction(withinTx: Transactable.() -> Unit) : Transactable {
    init {
        start()
        try {
            withinTx()
            commit()
        } catch (ex: Throwable) {
            rollback()
            throw ex
        }
    }

    private fun start() { ... }

    override fun Entity.save(tx: Transactable) { ... }
    override fun Entity.delete(tx: Transactable) { ... }

    override fun Transactable.commit() { ... }
    override fun Transactable.rollback() { ... }
}


class Person : Entity { ... }
class Movie : Entity { ... }
```

**Later, we decide to add:**

```
class MovieTransactions(val movie: Movie, 
                        tx: Transactable, 
                        withTx: MovieTransactions.()->Unit): Transactable by tx {
    init {
        this.withTx()
    }

    fun swapActor(originalActor: Person, replacementActor: Person) {
        // `this` is the transaction
        // `movie` is the movie
        movie.removeActor(originalActor)
        movie.addActor(replacementActor)
        save(movie)
    }

    // ...and other complex functions
}

fun Transactable.forMovie(movie: Movie, withTx: MovieTransactions.()->Unit) {
    MovieTransactions(movie, this, withTx)
}
```

**Now using the new functionality:**

```
fun castChanges(swaps: Pair<Person, Person>, film: Movie) {
    Transaction {
        forMovie(film) {
            swaps.forEach { 
                // only available here inside forMovie() lambda
                swapActor(it.first, it.second) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or this whole thing could just have been a top level extension function on `Transactable` if you didn't mind it being at the top level, not in a class, and cluttering up the namespace of the package.

For other examples of using intermediary classes, see:

- in Klutter TypeSafe config module, an intermediary object is used to store the state of "which property" can be acted upon, so it can be passed around and also changes what other methods are available. `config.value("something").asString()` ([code link](https://github.com/kohesive/klutter/blob/master/config-typesafe-jdk6/src/main/kotlin/uy/klutter/config/typesafe/TypesafeConfig_Ext.kt#L20))
- in Klutter Netflix Graph module, an intermediary object is used to transition to another part of the DSL grammar `connect(node).edge(relation).to(otherNode)`.  ([code link](https://github.com/kohesive/klutter/blob/master/netflix-graph-jdk6/src/main/kotlin/uy/klutter/graph/netflix/internal/Building.kt#L103-L105))  The [test cases](https://github.com/kohesive/klutter/blob/master/netflix-graph-jdk6/src/test/kotlin/uy/klutter/graph/netflix/TestNetflixGraph.kt) in the same module show more uses including how even operators such as `get()` and `invoke()` are available only in context.

Comment: Sounds almost like a GoF State Pattern. :) Maybe you could extract a pattern out of this for Kotlin.

Comment: Haven't heard GoF in a long time.

Comment: Old question, but great answer! I'm trying to solve a problem and I've figured it out with something like this solution. Is there any other examples/articles you know of? I just don't even know a name for this

Comment: @PrestonGarno You would want to look up DSL Builder articles and topics around Kotlin.  This is the area it most likely to discuss these topics.