# Getting access to an instance in a wrapper function

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I have this function to wrap a transaction:

```
fun wrapInTransaction(code: () -> Unit) {
        realmInstance.beginTransaction();
        code.invoke()
        realmInstance.commitTransaction();
}
```

How can I get access to `realmInstance` in the invoked code?

Comment: Almost the same code is present in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797366/in-kotlin-how-do-i-add-extension-methods-to-another-class-but-only-visible-in and explained in the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34797367/3679676 where the transaction itself wraps the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers correctly demonstrate how to pass the `RealmInstance` object to the lambda. In addition, you can make the whole function an extension function which makes the call site a bit prettier:

```
fun Realm.wrapInTransaction(code: Realm.() -> Unit) {
    //this is implicit
    beginTransaction();
    code()
    commitTransaction();
}
```

The call site will look like this:

```
Realm.getInstance(this).wrapInTransaction {
    createObject(User.class)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easy solution here is to make `code` a [function with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver):

```
fun wrapInTransaction(code: Realm.() -> Unit) {
    realmInstance.beginTransaction();
    realmInstance.code()
    realmInstance.commitTransaction();
}
```

Inside a lambda which you pass as `code` you will be able to use `this` to reference the `RealmInstance` and to use its members directly as if inside a member function.

Calling `realmInstance.code()` is just calling `code` with passing `realmInstance` as a receiver to it.

Comment: It's even better to make the whole function an extension function.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `wrapInTransaction` function to accept an extensions method on `realmInstance` like so:

```
fun wrapInTransaction(code:Realm.() -> Unit){
    realmInstance.beginTransaction();
    realmInstance.code()
    realmInstance.commitTransaction();
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
wrapInTransaction {
    println("realm instance is $this, instanceId: $instanceId")
}
```

Where for the sake of the example the `Realm` looks like:

```
class Realm {
    val instanceId = 42
    fun beginTransaction() {
    }

    fun commitTransaction() {
    }
}
```

The above technique is possible thanks to Kotlin's [Function Literals with Receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) that make it possible to *set* the `this` instance (receiver) within lambda function body. It makes it easy to build type safe builders that reassemble ones from Groovy or Ruby.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797366/in-kotlin-how-do-i-add-extension-methods-to-another-class-but-only-visible-in) provides more samples on the technique.