# Add an extensions function to Math class in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, extension-methods

I added a function to `Math` class in the Kotlin but I could not use it, I did this before with `MutableList` and it worked but I can not do it with `Math` class.

```
fun Math.divideWithSubtract(num1: Int, num2: Int) = 
Math.exp(Math.log(num1.toDouble())) - Math.exp(Math.log(num2.toDouble()))
```

Comment: Suggested reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317940/when-should-one-prefer-kotlin-extension-functions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use this extension on Math on a static level because extensions only work on instances. **edit**: Since Math cannot be instantiated, you won't be able to use extensions on it.

If you really want that method as an extension, you should extend Int instead :

```
fun Int.divideWithSubtract(otherInt: Int) = 
    Math.exp(Math.log(this.toDouble())) - Math.exp(Math.log(otherInt.toDouble()))
```

And you would use it like this :

```
val result = 156.divideWithSubstract(15) //:Double
```

---

If you really want to have static-ish methods, in Java and Kotlin as well, you could always define any method on package level in a kotlin file.

Thus, some `doSomething(args)`method in a `Util.kt` file would be accessible anywhere in any Kotlin file and you would have to call `UtilKt.doSomething()` in Java.

see : [Package level functions in the official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use it like static java methods, but only on `Math` objects.. That is why it worked on `MutableList` because you used it **on a list**.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to extend `Math` here? Extending makes sense, when you have a receiver type (like `String` e.g.), whose **instances** you want to extend. Math is just a util class and *cannot be instantiated*, i.e. it's not possible to provide an appropriate **receiver** to the function.

Just create this method on top level for example:

```
fun divideWithSubtract(num1: Int, num2: Int) =
        Math.exp(Math.log(num1.toDouble())) - Math.exp(Math.log(num2.toDouble()))
```