# Ways to obfuscate access to prefereably private, but actually public class members for the sake of using them in inline methods

Tags: inline, visibility, kotlin

What are some ways to obfuscate or limit access to public members of a class?

The motivation behind doing this is that I would like to be able to `inline` a method, but it needs access to other members in the class, which requires them to be `public`, however I would prefer these members to be anything but `public`, but since they must be `public`, I am looking for ways to obfuscate or limit access to them.

Here is an example of such a case where I would prefer `preferablyPrivateLock` to be private:

```
class SomeClass
{
    val preferablyPrivateLock = ReentrantLock()

    inline fun <R> fancyInlineFunction(function:()->R):R
    {
        preferablyPrivateLock.lock()
        try
        {
            return function()
        }
        finally
        {
            preferablyPrivateLock.unlock()
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I know this seems like bad OO design; hope this question doesn't cost me any reputation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same can be done without `Unit` by having the method be an extension on its own class, in this case `SomeClass`.  This simplifies the usage:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private val preferablyPrivateLock = ReentrantLock()
    val SomeClass.hiddenLock: ReentrantLock
        get() = preferablyPrivateLock

    inline fun <R> fancyInlineFunction(function:()->R):R
    {
        with(this) { hiddenLock }.lock()
        try
        {
            return function()
        }
        finally
        {
            with(this) { hiddenLock }.unlock()
        }
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    fun foo() {
        val x = SomeClass().hiddenLock // ERROR: Unresolved reference hiddenLock
    }
}
```

This solution was mentioned by @Kirill in Kotlin Slack.  It is similar technique to this: [In Kotlin, how do I add extension methods to another class, but only visible in a certain context?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34797366/3679676)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to obfuscate access to `preferablyPrivateLock` with the help of [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html):

```
class SomeClass
{
    private val preferablyPrivateLock = ReentrantLock()
    val Unit.obfuscatedLock:ReentrantLock
        get() = preferablyPrivateLock

    inline fun <R> fancyInlineFunction(function:()->R):R
    {
        with(this) {Unit.obfuscatedLock}.lock()
        try
        {
            return function()
        }
        finally
        {
            with(this) {Unit.obfuscatedLock}.unlock()
        }
    }
}
```