# How to add custom view groups to Anko DSL?

Tags: kotlin, anko

[Anko docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/doc/ADVANCED.md#extending-anko) tell us how to add custom views to DSL. But if my custom view is a view group, problems arise.

```
class MyFrameLayout(context: Context) : FrameLayout(context)

fun ViewManager.myFrameLayout(init: MyFrameLayout.() -> Unit = {}) = ankoView({ MyFrameLayout(it) }, init)

class MyUI : AnkoComponent<Fragment> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<Fragment>) = with(ui) {

        myFrameLayout {
            textView("hello").lparams { // error: Unresolved reference: lparams
                bottomMargin = dip(40)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but if I change `myFrameLayout` invocation to `frameLayout` it works OK. So what's the proper way to make view groups be used with Anko DSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take a look at Anko sources we can see that `frameLayout` actualy returns an instance of `_FrameLayout` class, where these `lparams` functions are defined. In my understanding this is needed, so these `lparams` functions are only available in the layout building code.

In Anko's `Layouts.kt` file there are these `_<ViewGroup>` classes for every supported `ViewGroup`.

So the straightforward way to support a custom view group is to create a `_<ViewGroup>` class with `lparams` methods implementation. The problem is that this `_<ViewGroup>` class often contains much more code than my `<ViewGroup>` itself!

And if I want create many custom view groups, adding Anko support for them becomes a big pain with this approach. Let's say I have `MyFrameLayout1`, `MyFrameLayout2`, `MyFrameLayout3` classes. They are basically `FrameLayout`'s so I want the same layout parameters to be used with them. But I have to create `_FrameLayout1`, `_FrameLayout2`, `_FrameLaoyt3` classes which are just copy/paste of Anko's `_FrameLayout`.

So I slightly improved this approach. I create an `interface _FrameLayout`:

```
interface _FrameLayout {
    // copy/paste from Anko's _FrameLayout
}
```

and now to support any custom `FrameLayout` subclass I just have to:

```
class _MyFrameLayout(ctx: Context) : MyFrameLayout(ctx), _FrameLayout

fun ViewManager.myFrameLayout(init: _MyFrameLayout.() -> Unit = {})= ankoView({ _MyFrameLayout(it) }, init)
```

This reduces copy/paste a lot, when creating many custom view groups.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you just have to extend anko and declare your customview then use it in the DSL normally:

```
public inline fun ViewManager.customView() = customView {}
public inline fun ViewManager.customView(init: CustomView.() -> Unit) = ankoView({ CustomView(it) }, init)
```

Then use it in the DSL normally

```
frameLayout {
    customView()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you inherit from e.g. `_RelativeLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`, you can use your custom layout as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to any of Anko's `lparams` declarations from your code, you can see that inside Anko generated DSL code, `lparams` is an extension function for `T: View` which looks like this:

```
fun <T: View> T.lparams(
        width: Int = android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        height: Int = android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        init: android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.() -> Unit = defaultInit
): T {
    val layoutParams = android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)
    layoutParams.init()
    this@lparams.layoutParams = layoutParams
    return this
}
```

(and more overloads for different `LayoutParams` constructors)

It is declared inside a class, so it is only visible in functions with a receiver of that class, see [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797366/in-kotlin-how-do-i-add-extension-methods-to-another-class-but-only-visible-in) about this method of DSL programming.

---

In order to be able to use `lparams` for your custom `ViewGroup` in Anko DSL, you have to declare a similar function or functions inside your custom view code, that will create an appropriate `LayoutParams` for your class.

If you want also to hide `lparams` function from outside the DSL, you can make a subclass of your `MyFrameLayout` and use it in DSL code only, working with `MyFrameLayout` itself elsewhere.

After that, you can call `lparams` on any `View` inside a lambda which you pass as `init: MyFrameLayout.() -> Unit` to `fun ViewManager.myFrameLayout`.